# Spring MongoDB UUID support

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, uuid, spring-mongodb

I want to use `UUID` instead of the plain `String` value for fields annotated with `@Id`, for example:

```
@Data // Lombok
public class Role {

    @Id
    private UUID id;

    @Size(max = 18)
    private String name;

}
```

However, inserting such object leads to `Cannot autogenerate id of type java.util.UUID for entity of type Role` exception.

For reference, I've tried the following custom configuration with no success:

```
@Configuration
public class DatabaseConfiguration extends AbstractReactiveMongoConfiguration {

    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return "test";
    }

    @Override
    public void configureClientSettings(MongoClientSettings.Builder builder) {
        builder.uuidRepresentation(UuidRepresentation.STANDARD); // <---
    }
    
}
```

Are there any approaches to make it work **WITHOUT creating custom** `AbstractMongoEventListener` per each model (creating one for the base class does not work either)?

Answer (score -1):

Currently, generating IDs of data types other than ObjectId, String or BigInteger wasn't directly possible before Spring Data MongoDB 2.0, 1.10.1 and 1.9.8.

For more details see: https://craftingjava.com/blog/custom-document-id-spring-data-mongodb/

As an extra thought on the workaround with `CustomMongoRepositoryImpl`, you can create a custom aspect annotation as a universal mount point for all repositories, and within that aspect, you can have a mapping between client id types and generators.

Comment: The proposed solution within that link uses `AbstractMongoEventListener`, which is against what I'm looking for (as stated in my post).

Comment: I meant to consider the solution with CustomMongoRepositoryImpl

Comment: This solution is meant for older versions and is even worse than creating multiple `AbstractMongoEventListener` only.